# MongoDB Aggregate Functions

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do a group by on a MongoDB collection (my version is 2.2.2)

```
db.stream.aggregate({$group: { MyId:"A1"}})
```

But I get the following error:

```
19 11:56:20 TypeError: db.stream.aggregate is not a function (shell):1
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you are using 2.2 shell and not just the 2.2 server?

Comment: FYI: you can type at mongo shell prompt > version() to get the version of the shell or > db.version() to get the version of the server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must be using 2.2.+ version of the *shell* to be able to use the `aggregate` helper.

You can check the shell version with `version()` command at the shell prompt.

In addition, your aggregation syntax is incorrect - the `$group` operator must set a field called `_id` (you have `MyId`) which is what tells it which field you are aggregating by.

Comment: It's not working for me. Shell version is 2.4 and mongo version is 3+ still getting same error.